# How to sum(amount) and group by user_id on the same table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with a lot of rows per user_id

and i am trying to group rows by user_id  and to sum their amount

This is the table structure

```
Name    Type    Collation   Attributes  Null    Default Extra   Action
 1  user_id int(11)         No          None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 2  amount  decimal(16,8)   No          None         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 3  aff int(11)             No             0         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 4  jackpot int(11)         No             0         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 5  paidout int(11)         No             0         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 6  type    int(11)         No             0         Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
 7  created timestamp       No   CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   Change Change   Drop Drop   Browse distinct values Browse distinct values   Primary Primary     Unique Unique  Show more actions More
```

I am trying this query without success:

> update trans
>   SELECT * FROM  trans group by user_id 
>   set amount = (select sum(amount) from trans

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: do you want to insert the results into another table or what do you want? where is your problem?

Comment: No, i want to update the same table

Comment: There is a flaw in your logic... you're wanting to update the field to be the sum of itself?  If you really intend on updating the table, you should be updating a different column.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like this :

```
UPDATE trans t
    INNER JOIN (
        select user_id, sum(amount) sumAmount
        from trans
        group by user_id
    ) subSum on subSum.user_id = t.user_id
SET t.amount = subSum.sumAmount
```

#### With user_id range :

```
UPDATE trans t
    INNER JOIN (
        select user_id, sum(amount) sumAmount
        from trans
        where user_id BETWEEN 0 AND 1000 --Edited
        group by user_id
    ) subSum on subSum.user_id = t.user_id
SET t.amount = subSum.sumAmount
WHERE t.user_id BETWEEN 0 AND 1000 --HEre
```

#### With a temp table

Using temp table :

```
--Create table with user_id and sum amount
CREATE TABLE trans_temp_sum_amount 
SELECT user_id, sum(amount) sumAmount
FROM trans
GROUP BY user_id;

--Update
UPDATE trans t
    INNER JOIN trans_temp_sum_amount subSum 
        on subSum.user_id = t.user_id
SET t.amount = subSum.sumAmount;

--Drop temp table 
DROP TABLE trans_temp_sum_amount;
```

Comment: can this be done in parts , because runnign this query on this table with all these rows, blocks phpmyadmin totally

Comment: I really don't know why, the only suggestion I can give you is to use a table to save the sum and then update your final table, and drop the temp table. Or limit the number of user, with a `WHERE user_id BETWEEN 0 AND 1000` then `1000 AND 2O00`...

Comment: If i want to try the fist option , where should i add the WHERE user_id BETWEEN 0 AND 1000

Comment: I updated the answer for the temp table solution. For the where, place it after the SET and after the group by. I edit a second time.

Comment: Does not work i get this error With user_id range ::    #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'where user_id BETWEEN 0 AND 1000 --Here ) subSum on subSum.user_id = t.user' at line 6

Comment: My bad, where clause is before group by

Comment: Still the query blocks the phpMyadmin even doing it with WHERE user_id BETWEEN 20 AND 100       is there any other way to update trans

Comment: Like I told you, use the temp table as I described in my answer.

Comment: I tried that too and still blocking phpMyadmin , anyway please can you update the code to use the temp table by parts like WHERE user_id BETWEEN 0 AND 1000

Comment: It won't help my friend, I really cannot help you more, my knowledge is limited on mysql phpmyadmin.

Comment: Now i tested the query with a small table and the result is that it updates the amount but the number rows stays as it was , the query does not collapse the rows just makes the sum of the amounts and repeats the balance on every row  by the same id

Answer (score 0):

i would advise you to use a VIEW instead of *"deleting"* all your *old* data:

```
CREATE VIEW trans_view AS
SELECT user_id, SUM(amount) FROM trans GROUP BY user_id;
```

And i would advise you to have a look at your program and try to update the `amount` every time it changes instead of insert a new row every time.